# Perl regex: split inside percent character "%"

Tags: regex, string, perl, split

I'm trying to split a string by nested char "%",

for example I've this string 
`"Welcome to %aaatext%, discount 50% and you'll get %bbbtext%, thanks"`

in this case the result I expected:

```
(0) [Welcome to ]
(1) [aaatext]
(2) [, discount 50% and you'll get ]
(3) [bbbtext]
(4) [, thanks]
```

I have tried the following code

```
my @arr = split /\%.*text\%/, $str;
```

but the results were far from expectations :(

```
(0) [Welcome to ]
(1) [, thanks]
```

in that case is it possible to use regex for split?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How does your code know whether to extract `%aaatext%` or `%aaatext%, discount 50%` ? Counting `%` won't help you either, consider `"Welcome to %aaatext%, discounts are 50% and 70% for silver and gold card holders, resp., and you'll get %bbbtext%, thanks"`. You need to specify a pattern for the strings between `%`s serving as delimiters.

Comment: Yeah, why is the second desired item `, discount 50% and you'll get ` and not `, discount 50`?

Comment: `split /(%\w*text%)/`? `split /(%[^ %]*text%)/`?

Comment: Isn't literal "%" supposed to be escaped in this use by using `%%`? (Assuming CMD.exe.) Parsers may break due to trying to find an ending % after the % in 50%.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Perl one-liner:

```
% cat > input_file <<EOF                                                             
Welcome to %aaatext%, discount 50% and you'll get %bbbtext%, thanks
EOF

% perl -lne 'print for split m{ % ( \w* text ) % }x, $_;' input_file
Welcome to 
aaatext
, discount 50% and you'll get 
bbbtext
, thanks
```

Here,
`m{}x` is the regex with `x` modifier, causing Perl to ignore whitespace and comments inside the regex, for readability,
`\w*` is 0 or more word characters,
`% ( \w* text ) %` captures word ending with `text` flanked on both sides with percent signs, enabling `split` to return those as well.